# How to create an algorithms for fitting a network of tubes into a cube?

Tags: pipelines

How to create an algorithms for fitting a network of tubes with a range of diameters into a cube, with maximum volume in the tubes? Assume:

- 30 cm minimum square side
- 1 cm minimum pipe diameter
- 1 mm pipe wall thickness.
- Cube edge length $L$
- number of different diameters $n$
- volume Pipes $= \pi r^2\times\text{length}$.

The tubes form a network in the sense of a continuous network of connected Tubes.

Tricky parts:

- Finding the ideal number of different radiuses of pipes to use.
- accounting for curves in the pipes. May be worth assuming straight pipes with U-turns at the ends? Obviously square pipes would be ideal. But we are restricted to circular pipes.

Best to break down the problem into components:

1. assuming (one) 1 cm diameter pipe, how to fit most volume pipe into 30cm cube.
2. assuming (multiple) diameter pipes: 1 cm and 5 cm diameter pipes, how to fit most volume pipe into 30 cm cube.
3. how to determine the optimal number of diameters
   i. given limited number or radii,
   ii. given unlimited number of radii.

Comment: use the smallest pipes you can, they pack best. You haven't really given any constraints to the length of the pipe, or if there are any turns.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing

Comment: "they pack best" - not necessarily. You can fit small pipes into the spaces left between bigger pipes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonian_gasket

Comment: What's the purpose of this exercise?

Comment: Ambiguity: Is the minimum diameter constraint internal or external diameter?  If it's external then the wall thickness is immaterial.

Comment: @Wossname if its external, then the wall thickness still is significant for the calculation of the volume of liquid contained.

Comment: @Dale, You have specified a constant 1mm wall thickness.  So it does not affect the algorithm.

Comment: This is a semi-traditional [Packing Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problems), but you haven't been given / provided a sufficient number of constraints for the community to provide much guidance beyond identification of the type of problem.  Specifically, you need to address how corners need to be accounted for and whether the pipes need to be contiguous or not.  From there, you need to present a specific issue within developing your solution to the packing problem for the community to be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

If you assume that your pipes are straight, your problem reduces to 2D circle packing as Mohammad suggests. But unlike what he says, using the smallest pipes wont get you the best packing density:

> For seven of these radius ratios a compact packing is known that
>   achieves the maximum possible packing fraction (above that of
>   uniformly-sized discs) for mixtures of discs with that radius ratio.
>   The highest packing density is 0.911627478 for a radius ratio of
>   0.545151042.
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing

However, in order to write a meaningful algorithm you need to have a minimum diameter constraint, otherwise you will be able to fill the gaps with increasingly smaller tubes.

You may find better responses for this question on [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: A critical component that you've omitted here (and is never included in standard circle packing theory) is wall thickness. If you have one choice of diameter, smaller pipes have less wasted space outside the pipes, but a whole lot more wasted space in the metal walls compared to larger pipes. Larger pipes also need thicker walls, but this will be smaller in comparison to the diameter than for small pipes. There is an optimum diameter, but calculating it depends on the material of pipes, pressure they must sustain, heat transfer requirements, etc.

Comment: True, I assumed that wall thickness is negligible, which may not be the case for this problem.